# Need to discard an entire branch and merge again - how?

Tags: git

Not sure if this is possible. Git newbie here.

We are working with two branches. "`dev`" and "master"; the "`dev`" branch is ok. The "`master`" branch is a mess.

I would like to remove everything on the "`master`" branch, and then merge the "`dev`" to that "cleaned" master branch ?

Is this possible, or advisable ?

Note: I'm using a remote hub repository as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you completely want to discard the `master` branch, in that case, why not simply delete it and branch off `dev`?

```
git checkout dev
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
git push origin +master
```

That last `git push` will force an update to your `origin` remote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do those simple steps:

revert all the changes in your master and the add new code as the first commit:

```
git revert HEAD~XXX (where XXX is the number fo the commits you wish to delete)
```

now add the files you want to add to your branch

Once you are satisfy with your state push the updated code you have to enforce the change to the remote branch by using the +
the (+) sign is update-force which set the code of branch to the updated code regardless of what you have on the remote one

```
git push origin +master
```

Answer (score 0):

A branch in Git is really just a pointer to a commit. If you think about it like that it is simple.

```
git branch -d master
git checkout dev
git branch master
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to use stash:
stash all your current changes so master will become clean

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing